# PCB antenna connector and copper signal names

Tags: antenna, eaglecad, pcb-antenna

I am trying to build a PCB antenna similar to what is shown in [this video.](https://youtu.be/JeUexihrKZQ?t=384) At the 6:24 mark it shows the circuit layout below:

[image]

I am using Eagle to layout the PCB on a two layer board.  `Red` is copper on the top of the board and `blue` is copper on bottom of board.

I am using a part from a library for an antenna mount.  This mount is so that this PCB antenna can connect to a separate transceiver Lora board.  The center pin is the signal feed.  The other four pins are (I'm guessing here) the ground.  I have attempted to layout the circuit myself.

Here is the schematic and the board.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The connector is shown on the info layer as being to right angle of board, but the connector fits for a variant which has the connector straight up towards viewer.

The vias were added and a ground plane in blue beneath the lower portion.  The vias connect to the bottom ground plane but not the the top layer `Ant` signal connected to signal feed center pin. During bring-up these can be used forexperimentation by hand soldering via on top.  These vias were added according to Figure 3 sub figure A in this wikipedia [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted-F_antenna).

In the video, he is showing the four ground pins with the heavy bold vertical lines by the antenna mount.  Are these "gnd" or "mount" pins connected to the signal pin?  I think not.

So the final question is, is the net/signal name "Ant" which is the entire top pour region and the center pin, also connected to the four pads for the antenna "ground," or should it be implemented as shown in the layout?

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to design a planar / PCB element like this, is to use net bridges.  This is a component which is allowed to short between two nets.  Usually the copper objects within the "net bridge" tagged component are ignored for checking connectivity, or you might need to create an exception rule which targets the component specifically.

You could use a net bridge in two ways:

1. Make a full and proper antenna component, which might include mechanical fiducials for aligning it with the board edge, keepouts to prevent polygon pours within its bounds, etc., and which consists of two pads (e.g., one where the antenna 'L' joins the main board's ground plane, one where the feedline trace overlaps the ground plane).
2. Draw the geometry as here, and net bridge just the feedline.  Or just the ground return path, or anywhere inbetween really.  This is more of a shortcut "get off my back, DRC" but without fixing anything about the geometry inbetween, enforcing keep-outs (other than what you place in the design), etc.

This way, top and bottom pours can both be GND, the stitching vias will join, the connector pads will join, etc.

Disclaimer, I don't use EAGLE so I can't show how to construct this specifically.  This seems relevant for further reading: 
[How do I facilitate keeping multiple grounds, (i.e. AGND, DGND, etc...) separated in the layout when using Eagle?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/23495/how-do-i-facilitate-keeping-multiple-grounds-i-e-agnd-dgnd-etc-separate)

Answer (score 0):

Those 4 GND pins/pads on the connector are soldered or otherwise attached to the lower ground plane, the copper part that's lambda/4 high.  They are not connected to the center pin - the RF feed - of the connector.

If you were to do that, you would just be shorting the RF to ground.

Comment: The copper pour below is connected.  Where do I break signal feed connection to antenna pour?

Comment: Ill modify the question to clarify the comment above.